# TeXStudio: Autocomplete missing for some commands (acronym pkg)

Tags: texstudio, acronyms, auto-completion

I'm using TeXstudio 3.1.1 (git 3.1.1) on Windows 10 to write a TeX document with BibLaTeX bibliography.
The document uses [this KOMA thesis template](https://github.com/novoid/LaTeX-KOMA-template).

To support using acronyms, I use the `acronym` package. While TeXstudio usually is great in recommending and auto-completing commands as I type, it does not recommend the `\ac{}` command, which I need really frequently for my acronyms.
In fact, it always suggests another command `\acute{}`, such that I always have to press ESC to cancel auto-complete to `\acute{}` and then manually type `\ac{}`. This is quite slow and annoying given that I need the command so often.

Any way to have TeXstudio correctly auto suggest and complete the `acronym` commands (like `\ac{}`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the auto-completion file for the `acronym` package is loaded, if that isn't the case for some reason.

You can achieve this by keeping the file containing `\usepackage{acronym}` open, as you suggested in your own answer,
or by having `acronym.cwl` permanently active (which may be especially useful for bigger projects like theses, where every open tab is a possible distraction).

Simply check the respective box under *Options* > *Configure TeXstudio...* > *Completion*:

[image]

(setting your main `.tex` file as *Root Document* should do the trick as well, I think)

Comment: That configuration option in TeXstudio is good to know - the best solution from my view! Btw, in my case, my main `.tex` is different from the `premable.tex`, in which I do the "imports", so setting my `main.tex` as Root Document didn't suffice here. But I guess that's a special case.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** Open the file in TeXstudio, where the package is imported with `\usepackage{}` to ensure that TeXstudio's auto complete works for that package.

---

As I was typing this question, I figured out the answer by accident. It's highly specific to my case, but I'll post it anyways in case it helps someone.

The issue is that I import `acronyms` with `\usepackage{acronyms}` not in my main document but in a separate `preamble.tex`.
If this preamble is not open in TeXstudio, the auto suggest and complete does not work.
Once I open the preamble in the editor, auto suggestion for `\ac{}` and all other `acronyms` commands works fine - until I close the preamble and restart TeXstudio.